# How can i run 'gcloud' and 'gsutil' command at datalab instance?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I've created datalab instance with the latest cli release. However, when I connect to it via `gcloud compute ssh` command, I cannot run commands like 'gcloud' and 'gsutil'. I'm receiving following message `-bash: gcloud: command not found`. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create) by using `--image-name` flag you can specify the image which you wish to create the Datalab VM instance from. If the flag is not used, the VM will be created using [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/). As mentioned in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#managing_software_on_container-optimized_os) Container-Optimized OS provides a toolbox wrapper to run debugging tools of your choice. For example, you can run the following command series to use `gcloud` and `gsutils` tools.

- first run  `toolbox`
- then run `gcloud` or `gsutil`

Answer (score 2):

The VM is running a very small operating system (Container Optimized OS), which is designed to just run Docker containers.

That means that if you want to run tools like `gcloud` or `gsutil`, you are expected to run them inside of a Docker container that has them installed.

In the specific case of a Datalab instance, there should be a container running named `datalab` that has these tools installed.

After SSH'ing to the VM, you can connect to that container by running this command:

`docker exec -it datalab /bin/bash`